# How to check if a Blue Prism Server service is running?

Tags: scheduler, blueprism, rpa

I am trying to use the scheduler in Blue Prism and followed [this guide](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-09/Blue%20Prism%20-%20Guide%20to%20the%20Scheduler.pdf) to configure everything. However, my scheduled tasks are not running (nothing is started, there is no recent activity). One of the requirements to run a schedule is to have the blue prism server service running. How do I check this?

I have attached here some screenshots of my configured scheduler. The pending status on the timetable just disappears when I do "Run (schedule) now", and a checkmark never appears. The logs are also empty with no start or end time.

[image: Schedule]

[image: No activity]
[image: Timetable]

Comment: link to the guide requires login

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple - you're doing everything correct, but it's impossible to run a scheduler on the evaluate licence. Once you'll have a production licence and application server, then it should work as expected

Comment: I have a license type Enterprise. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 1):

have you got Blue Prism Server installed and running. You need to connect to SQL database through Blue Prism Server.
You can find instructions how to set up a Blue Prism Server locally here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXeNCJ60SMI
Finally you need to disable the interactive mode on your machine:
The interactive run mode may be disabled via System Manager in System, Settings, (uncheck “Start the process engine on this machine when users sign in”) in order to avoid it conflicting with the Resource PC mode, for example).
And run a separate instance of Blue Prism as resource pc from command line:
"C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\Automate.exe" /resourcepc /public /dbconname ""